# How to add azure dev ops as continuous development in python web app on azure

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops

I have created a `python` web app on azure. I also have `devOps` where I have repository and all the python flask API code.

In azure python web app, under deployment center. I have selected the `Azure DevOps` and have selected my organization, project, repo and branch. It also has an option of selecting the web application framework in which I think I need to select `Python` but there is no option of selecting `python`. If I do not select any framework and click `continue`, nothing happens. Can anyone please help me in setting this up. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using a `Linux` web app, if so, there is no `Python` option in `Web Application Framework`, it is just available in the `Windows` web app.

Comment: Very strange. It should be there for linux as well.

Comment: @SAndrew Looks the existing options correspond to this [table](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/or1SF.png , https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD7MD.png